# Nodemailer working on Localhost, not on live Netlify site

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios, nodemailer

I have used nodemailer/axios to get information from a form to be sent to an e-mail address.

When the site is run with localhost:3000 the mail gets sent no problem, although live it does not come through.

I am assuming it has to be something to do with the proxy?

This is what my code looks like which works:

```
const proxy = require('http-proxy-middleware')

module.exports = function(app) {

    app.user(proxy("/api", { target: "http://localhost:3000"}))
}
```

the live site is at: https://deathless-studio.netlify.com/#/

I tried changing the target to that, as well as: https://deathless-studio.netlify.com/ and also http://deathless-studio.netlify.com/#/, although no mail gets sent through.

I always get these errors:

```
https://deathless-studio.netlify.com/api/v1/sendMail 404

POST https://deathless-studio.netlify.com/api/v1/sendMail 404
```

my send mail function looks like this:

```
const sendEmail = (name, email, message, newsletter) => {

    const smtpTransport = mailer.createTransport({
        service: "Gmail",
        auth: {
            user: "(correct email)",
            pass: "(correct password)"
        }
    })


    const mail = getEmailData(name, email, message, newsletter)

    smtpTransport.sendMail(mail, function(error, response) {
        if(error) {
            console.log(error)
        } else {
            alert( "Thank you! We will be in touch shortly!")
        }
        smtpTransport.close();
    })
```

the handleSubmit function on my Form Component looks like this also:

```
   handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const data = {
      name: this.state.name,
      email: this.state.email,
      message: this.state.message,
      newsletter: this.state.newsletter
    };

    Axios.post("api/v1/sendMail", data)

    alert( "Thank you! We will be in touch shortly!")
   }
```

and my index.js looks like this:

```
const server = require("./server");


const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");

server.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
server.use(bodyParser.json());
server.use(cookieParser());

const { sendEmail } = require("../server/routes/mail");

server.post("/api/v1/sendMail", (req, res) => {
  sendEmail(req.body.name, req.body.email, req.body.message, req.body.newsletter);
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

server.listen(port, () => {
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
  console.log("Server listening on port", port);
});
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out Netlify doesn't use a Node.js server and you can use their plugins instead.

This article explains it:
https://community.netlify.com/t/node-js-wont-start-trying-to-run-a-server-on-netlify/3454/2?fbclid=IwAR0wc4iLhFdS-_dZF4TGPyzONmfHQxwfEztNFO2oTTlonrsBwCF73Xf7QNY

Comment: so how did you fix it?